# Implicit none makes program inaccurate

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am writing a program that uses a given subroutine to calculate spherical Bessel functions. I modified the subroutine which gives a table into a function which only gives one value. However, I realized that when I call my function I need to have `IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)` in my program or it will give me a wrong value or error. Below I have included a sample program that works correctly.

```
! n = 3, x = 2 should return ~ 6.07E-2
program hello
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
    doubleprecision :: bessel, ans
    WRITE(*,*)'Please enter n and x '
    READ(*,*)N,X

    ans = bessel(N,X)

    print *, ans
end program

    SUBROUTINE SPHJ(N,X,NM,SJ,DJ)

!      =======================================================
!      Purpose: Compute spherical Bessel functions jn(x) and
!               their derivatives
!      Input :  x --- Argument of jn(x)
!               n --- Order of jn(x)  ( n = 0,1,??? )
!      Output:  SJ(n) --- jn(x)
!               DJ(n) --- jn'(x)
!               NM --- Highest order computed
!      Routines called:
!               MSTA1 and MSTA2 for computing the starting
!               point for backward recurrence
!      =======================================================

        IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
        DIMENSION SJ(0:N),DJ(0:N)
        NM=N
        IF (DABS(X).EQ.1.0D-100) THEN
           DO 10 K=0,N
              SJ(K)=0.0D0
10            DJ(K)=0.0D0
           SJ(0)=1.0D0
           DJ(1)=.3333333333333333D0
           RETURN
        ENDIF
        SJ(0)=DSIN(X)/X
        SJ(1)=(SJ(0)-DCOS(X))/X
        IF (N.GE.2) THEN
           SA=SJ(0)
           SB=SJ(1)
           M=MSTA1(X,200)
           IF (M.LT.N) THEN
              NM=M
           ELSE
              M=MSTA2(X,N,15)
           ENDIF
           F0=0.0D0
           F1=1.0D0-100
           DO 15 K=M,0,-1
              F=(2.0D0*K+3.0D0)*F1/X-F0
              IF (K.LE.NM) SJ(K)=F
              F0=F1
15            F1=F
           IF (DABS(SA).GT.DABS(SB)) CS=SA/F
           IF (DABS(SA).LE.DABS(SB)) CS=SB/F0
           DO 20 K=0,NM
20            SJ(K)=CS*SJ(K)
        ENDIF
        DJ(0)=(DCOS(X)-DSIN(X)/X)/X
        DO 25 K=1,NM
25         DJ(K)=SJ(K-1)-(K+1.0D0)*SJ(K)/X
        RETURN
        END


        INTEGER FUNCTION MSTA1(X,MP)

!      ===================================================
!      Purpose: Determine the starting point for backward
!               recurrence such that the magnitude of
!               Jn(x) at that point is about 10^(-MP)
!      Input :  x     --- Argument of Jn(x)
!               MP    --- Value of magnitude
!      Output:  MSTA1 --- Starting point
!      ===================================================

        IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
        A0=DABS(X)
        N0=INT(1.1*A0)+1
        F0=ENVJ(N0,A0)-MP
        N1=N0+5
        F1=ENVJ(N1,A0)-MP
        DO 10 IT=1,20
           NN=N1-(N1-N0)/(1.0D0-F0/F1)
           F=ENVJ(NN,A0)-MP
           IF(ABS(NN-N1).LT.1) GO TO 20
           N0=N1
           F0=F1
           N1=NN
 10        F1=F
 20     MSTA1=NN
        RETURN
        END


        INTEGER FUNCTION MSTA2(X,N,MP)

!      ===================================================
!      Purpose: Determine the starting point for backward
!               recurrence such that all Jn(x) has MP
!               significant digits
!      Input :  x  --- Argument of Jn(x)
!               n  --- Order of Jn(x)
!               MP --- Significant digit
!      Output:  MSTA2 --- Starting point
!      ===================================================

        IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
        A0=DABS(X)
        HMP=0.5D0*MP
        EJN=ENVJ(N,A0)
        IF (EJN.LE.HMP) THEN
           OBJ=MP
           N0=INT(1.1*A0)
        ELSE
           OBJ=HMP+EJN
           N0=N
        ENDIF
        F0=ENVJ(N0,A0)-OBJ
        N1=N0+5
        F1=ENVJ(N1,A0)-OBJ
        DO 10 IT=1,20
           NN=N1-(N1-N0)/(1.0D0-F0/F1)
           F=ENVJ(NN,A0)-OBJ
           IF (ABS(NN-N1).LT.1) GO TO 20
           N0=N1
           F0=F1
           N1=NN
10         F1=F
20      MSTA2=NN+10
        RETURN
        END

        REAL*8 FUNCTION ENVJ(N,X)
        DOUBLE PRECISION X
        ENVJ=0.5D0*DLOG10(6.28D0*N)-N*DLOG10(1.36D0*X/N)
        RETURN
        END

!end of file msphj.f90

doubleprecision function bessel(N,X)
implicit doubleprecision(A-Z)
    DIMENSION SJ(0:250),DJ(0:250)
    integer :: N

    CALL SPHJ(N,X,N,SJ,DJ)

    bessel = SJ(N)

end function
```

And here is a sample program that does not work, using the same function.

```
program hello
    IMPLICIT none
    doubleprecision :: bessel, ans
    integer :: N, X
    WRITE(*,*)'Please enter n and x '
    READ(*,*)N,X

    ans = bessel(N,X)

    print *, ans

end program
```

I am relatively new to Fortran and don't understand why my program doesn't work. I appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: The sample program that does not work returns 1.00 as opposed to 6.07E-02

Comment: Do you need implicit at all in any part of your program? It is not a good practice to use implicit types. Put implicit none everywhere and give an explicit type to all variables.

Comment: Mark: The sample program uses the bessel implementation used in the program above it.

Comment: SPG: I don't need implicit types but when I try to give an explicit type to my variables in my sample program I get an incorrect answer

Comment: There you go then, the second argument to your implementation of `bessel` ought to be a real but you've specified an integer.  That's the kind of thing that happens when you program like it was 1979 -- always use `implicit none` and always put procedures into modules and `use` them so that the compiler checks that actual arguments match dummy arguments.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I used a real as my second argument and it worked correctly. To be fair, many of the subroutines I have to use are from FORTRAN 77. Additonally, I am new to Fortran but will look into modules. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you really are new to Fortran stop learning FORTRAN.  The 2008 standard for the language includes a number of bessel functions and most of the existing compilers in common use have jumped the gun and implemented them already.  Choose the function you want and get rid of that pile of ****.

Comment: I wish one could upvote @HighPerformanceMark 's comment unaccountably many times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the non working sample program uses the same implementation of `bessel` as the working sample.

If so, there is a conflict of type between the the type of `N` and `X` (`integer` in the non working main program) and the corresponding arguments in `bessel` which are all double precision per the specification

```
implicit doubleprecision(A-Z)
```

Everything in bessel is by default `doubleprecision`. Your main program must define `N` and `X` as `doubleprecision`.

The best solution as I said in the comment above is to use explicit typing everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I defined X as a doubleprecision explicitly and that seems to have fixed the problem. It now returns the correct value. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it solves the problem, accept the answer to help those who get similar problems in the future.